# In Bash, how can option flag values be stored in variables?

Tags: bash

When writing Bash scripts, how can I obtain a value from the command-line when provided as part of option flags in the command line?

For example in the following:

```
./script --value=myText --otherValue=100
```

How could I store the `myText` and `100` values in the variables `$text` and `$num`?

Comment: You'll have to use string manipulation, I'm not sure how it works in bash. [This site](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) seems to go through it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getopts.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If case you really need to use `--longoption`, if you can stick with a single char option `-a`, stick with what spraff said.
You can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
main()
{
    [[ $1 =~ "--value=(.*)" ]] && echo "First arg: $1"
    value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

    [[ $2 =~ "--otherValue=(.*)" ]] && echo "Second arg: $2"
    other=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

    echo $value
    echo $other

    #doYourThing

    return 0

}

main $*
```

Make sure you are running bash 3.0.

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.00.16(1)-release
```

If you have bash 4.x, do not put double quotes around the regex patterns.

Comment: Better be flexible about the order of options -- don't assume "--value" must be the first option. Use a `while` loop and `shift` the matched options.